# node.js "Usage of deprecated field: 'series'" while using c3 chart maker

Tags: node.js, c3.js

I am using c3 chart maker following the instructions of this github project: https://github.com/ashleydavis/nodejs-chart-rendering-example.

I would like to create a chart from a .csv data, however when i run the code below the chart is empty and I have this message: "Usage of deprecated field: 'series' ".

```
const c3ChartMaker = require('c3-chart-maker')

const inputFilePath = "./test_file.csv"
const chartDefinitionFile = "./chart.json"
const outputFilePath = "./chart.png"

c3ChartMaker(inputFilePath, chartDefinitionFile, outputFilePath)
   .then(() => {
      console.log('done')
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i test your code with this example: https://github.com/ashleydavis/c3-chart-maker
i use `example-chart.json` and `example-data.csv` in example folder and this is my code:

```
const c3ChartMaker = require('c3-chart-maker')

const inputFilePath = "./example-data.csv"
const chartDefinitionFile = "./example-chart.json"
const outputFilePath = "./example-js.png"


c3ChartMaker(inputFilePath, chartDefinitionFile, outputFilePath)
   .then(() => {
      console.log('done')
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
   })
```

when i run this code show me this image:
[image]

and on my console i have this message:

```
Usage of deprecated field: 'series'.
done
```

i read `index.js` code in `node_modules\c3-chart-maker` directory and find something:

```
if (chart.series) { // THIS SECTION IS DEPRECATED.
        console.error("Usage of deprecated field: 'series'.");

        if (!chart.data.columns) {
            chart.data.columns = [];
        }

        var series = Object.keys(chart.series);
        var dataFrame = new dataForge.DataFrame(data);
        series.forEach(seriesName => {
            var dataSeries = chart.series[seriesName];
            if (Sugar.Object.isString(inputData) && seriesName !== "x") {
                dataFrame = dataFrame.parseFloats(dataSeries).bake();
            }

            chart.data.columns.push(
                [seriesName].concat(
                    dataFrame.getSeries(dataSeries)
                        .select(v => v === undefined ? null : v)
                        .toArray()
                )
            )
        });
    }
```

you see this error log: `Usage of deprecated field: 'series'.` because in `example-chart.json` file we have this line of json:

```
"series": {
        "x": "Date",
        "Close": "Close",
        "Volume": "Volume"
    },
```

and `series` is deprecated.

Comment: I've changed the chart definition json by adding a "keys" key in it, however my chart is still empty. Do you perhaps have any experience with c3 chart maker to explain to me why is that ?

Comment: see this link: http://www.the-data-wrangler.com/node-js-chart-rendering-with-c3-and-nightmare/  and this link: https://c3js.org/reference.html and see this example csv link: https://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html . can you send your zip file to my email address?

Comment: Sure, is it on your profile ? I've looked a bit and didn't find it I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: taherfattahi11@gmail.com, I check my email

Comment: I think i solved my problem, the timeseries column was not in the right format. Thanks again for your help.